# How to add more row to the table in c#

Tags: datagridview

I have a problem and need help.

I'm a beginner in C# language and I designed a small program in it, but I'm having trouble tying the text box from multiple interfaces to a single table.

**Like:**
If the user clicks the button, the information is moved from the text box to the table and then back to find and add a new item to the table.

**Note:**
1- I want to know how to link without creating a database.
2- It is not HTML page is just simple form in c#.

Comment: can you provide an example of the expected functionality when you say "moved from the text box to the table and then back to find and add a new item to the table"

Comment: like shopping cart when you need to add more than one object from a different form